# Populating HtmlTable Control with HtmlTable object in ASP/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

It apparently doesn't seem to be an impossible question, but I can't find a way to populate an HtmlTable control (which is accessible from codebehind) with an HtmlTable object already filled with data.

Can anybody help me on this ??

Regards,

**EDIT**

In the ASP page, I have an HTML table with ID="table1"

In codebehind, I first populate an HtmlTable Object from a List doing like this :

```
HtmlTable localTable1 = new HtmlTable();
HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
HtmlTableCell cell2 = new HtmlTableCell();

foreach (Evaluation eval in theEvaluations)
{
    HtmlTableRow anEvaluation = new HtmlTableRow();

    cell1.InnerText = eval.attr1;
    anEvaluation.Cells.Add(cell1);

    cell2.InnerText = eval.attr2;
    anEvaluation.Cells.Add(cell2);

    localTable1.Rows.Add(anEvaluation);
}

// And eventually here I should pass the localTable1 to table1
```

Comment: Can you post some code so we can get a better idea what you are trying to do?

Comment: Will you please show some code so that we get an idea about what you have and how you are trying to do it?

Comment: Of course !! See the code snippet below

Comment: Usually you edit your question and add code there... usually :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I eventually have everything working, le remaining problem was just due to a wrong declaration place for the HtmlTableCell objects.

Here is a working snippet :

```
foreach (Evaluation eval in theEvaluations)
{
    HtmlTableRow anEvaluation = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
    HtmlTableCell cell2 = new HtmlTableCell();


    cell1.InnerText = eval.attr1;
    anEvaluation.Cells.Add(cell1);

    cell2.InnerText = eval.attr2;
    anEvaluation.Cells.Add(cell2);

    table1.Rows.Add(anEvaluation);  // table1 : the real HTML table in ASP page
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a table and you're trying to do something like

```
HtmlTable myTable = new HtmlTable();
this.myPageTable = myTable;
```

That's not how it works. If you have a populated table object you'd like to render then create a literal control and access it's Controls collection Add() method and add the table object. Like this:

```
HtmlTable myTable = new HtmlTable();
this.myLiteral.Controls.Add(myTable);
```

Or you should just populate the table directly.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, but the thing is I already have a precise table frame settled in my ASP page (Headers <th> are specified in it) and I just wanted to add rows below

Comment: Then you need to access the rows collection of the table object and create new HtmlTableRow() objects instead of a whole new table.

Comment: Ok, that's what I do now, and it adds a row to my ASP table but always and only the last record of my source list (which contains 2 elements) ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using <table> tags to create the table? If so, you should use the <asp:Table> tag and that will give you access to the table from the codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be passing the HtmlTable from the page to whatever function it is that is populating it, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the ASP page, I have an HTML table with ID="table1"

In codebehind, I first populate an HtmlTable Object from a List doing like this :

```
HtmlTable localTable1 = new HtmlTable();
HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
HtmlTableCell cell2 = new HtmlTableCell();

foreach (Evaluation eval in theEvaluations)
{
    HtmlTableRow anEvaluation = new HtmlTableRow();`

    cell1.InnerText = eval.attr1;
    anEvaluation.Cells.Add(cell1);

    cell1.InnerText = eval.attr1;
    anEvaluation.Cells.Add(cell2);

    localTable1.Rows.Add(anEvaluation);
}

// And eventually here I should pass the localTable1 to table1
```

Comment: You should edit your question if you need to add information instead of submitting an answer. I appended this to your question so you should just go ahead and delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're just creating work for yourself. There's no need to create all the rows in a local variable when you have a reference to the final destination right there.

Try this:

```
foreach (Evaluation eval in theEvaluations)
{
    HtmlTableRow anEvaluation = new HtmlTableRow();

    cell1.InnerText = eval.attr1;
    anEvaluation.Cells.Add(cell1);

    cell1.InnerText = eval.attr1;
    anEvaluation.Cells.Add(cell2);

    table1.Rows.Add(anEvaluation);
}
```

Comment: So the only way I found to add every different columns is to instantiate an HtmlTableCell for each one.

But then I have the same problem with the columns : Only the last one of my List "theEvaluations" is present in the ASP table at the end.

I checked the List.Count and there is more than one record in it ...