# Nest tables using HtmlTable

Tags: asp.net

> Possible duplicate:
>
> > [Populating HtmlTable Control with HtmlTable object in ASP/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294698/populating-htmltable-control-with-htmltable-object-in-asp-c)

I want to nest a table inside one of my HtmlTableRows

I tried to do this but it doesn't accept an HtmlTable:

```
HtmlTable someTable1 = new HtmlTable();
HtmlTable mainTable = new HtmlTable();

someTable1.Rows.Add(mainTable);
```

so that someTable would have a nested mainTable inside one of its rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [`HtmlTable.Rows.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablerowcollection.add%28VS.80%29.aspx) only accepts an `HtmlTableRow` object, not an `HtmlTable`.

To do what you want you need to add the second table to the [controls collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls%28VS.80%29.aspx) of a *cell* of the first. You should be able to set the [colspan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablecell.colspan%28VS.80%29.aspx) of that cell to encompass the whole outer table so that the inner table fills the entire width.

Something like this (not checked for syntax, constructor params etc.):

```
HtmlTable someTable1 = new HtmlTable();
HtmlTable mainTable = new HtmlTable();

HtmlTableRow myRow = new HtmlTableRow();
myRow.ColSpan = // Number of columns
HtmlTableCell myCell = new HtmlTableCell();

myCell.Controls.Add(mainTable);
myRow.Cells.Add(myCell);
someTable1.Rows.Add(myRow);
```

Comment: HtmlTableRow doesnt have ColSpan property - try HtmlTableCell.

Answer (score 1):

Create a row and cell in the first table - then add the second table inside that cell.